# What is the complexity (Big-O) of searching an indexed data in mongoDB?

Tags: regex, json, performance, mongodb

This is for a design issue. Can you tell me if i am indexing the key words as shown below.

```
obj = {
    name: "Apollo",
    text: "Some text about Apollo moon landings",
    tags: [ "moon", "apollo", "spaceflight" ]
}
```

Ensuring index  like this .

```
db.articles.ensureIndex( { tags: 1 } );
```

and  frequent query as follows.

```
db.articles.findOne( { tags: "apollo" } ).name
```

Please give me the performance of such query if i have n such documents inserted.

is it O(1) ?

And what is the performance for searching a regular expressions on such data.?

Answer (score 3):

This is a B-tree index, like in almost all databases, so it has O(log n) lookup time.

A regular expression search sounds like it needs to do a full table scan or a full index scan, both of which is O(n). If the expression is prefix-anchored, it would need to scan just a range, but I guess that still counts as O(n).

Comment: Is big o of n ever acceptable in nosql? Serious question.  I’m new to do development.

Comment: Depends how big N is and how fast you need it to return. It certainly does not scale well to large collections.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Thilo, MongoDB indexes are, implemented as "B-Tree" indexes and, fundamentally, indexes in MongoDB are operationally similar to indexes in other database systems. There is a good overview of indexes in MongoDB [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/).

I recommend reading about [indexing strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/) and [indexing operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/indexes/) to help with your implementation, administration and design.

To help analyse the performance of your queries and see what they're doing, you can append the explain() operator to the query. Please see [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) for further information on `explain()` and how to interpret its output.

MongoDB uses [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) for regular expressions. The usage is documented [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions). There are no size limitations other than those in the PCRE library. As with all regex, please bear in mind the consequence of a poorly constructed regex :)