# Internal mechanism of mongodb query by id

Tags: mongodb

Is there a direct mapping for the (default) _id in mongodb ??

```
db.model.findById({_id:xxxxxxxxxxxx})
```

or when we put a search based on the _id like the above one...it goes on kind of searching in the database for _id ?

In other words does the above query takes only **1 unit** of time or it takes **n units** of time depending on the size of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the field is indexed or not. If you have an index (like in the case of _id) the access time depends on the size of the database in term of O(logN). Without index it would be O(n).

More info: [MongoDB Index Complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920831/mongodb-index-complexity)